# Testing AppClip in TestFlight: Show Card?

Tags: swift, xcode, testflight, apple-appclips

Have created an app with an App Clip. The App Clip URL is showing as validated. A basic card has been set up in the app information on Connect.

Have set an invocation URL in TestFlight. Have downloaded ONLY the App Clip from TestFlight.

When using a QR code representing the URL, it invokes a "Web link" pop-up instead of an App Clip pop-up.

What can I do to test seeing the App Clip card via TestFlight? I feel like I'm either missing something or maybe it isn't possible in TestFlight.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- built and run the App Clip on your device (or install the App Clip via `TestFlight`)
- on your device go to `Settings` -> `Developer` -> `Local Experience`

  - if you don't see the `Developer` option, look up `enable Developer option iOS`
- register local experience that you want to test

  - set `URL PREFIX` to match the prefix of the URL you will scan with `QR` or `NFC`
  - make sure `BUNDLE ID` matches your clip's bundle id
- scan your QR code or NFC

There are still some weird issues around scanning the QR code so sometimes you have to use the `QR Scanner` from `Control Center` if the `Camera` app doesn't prompt the `App Clip` card.

Comment: That worked! I thought Local Experience only applied when you were running it locally, not when you distribute via TestFlight. But if I release on TestFlight to other users, I assume it will work without them needing to set up a Local Experience?

Comment: @dot3 sadly, I don’t think there is a way for regular testers to experience the App Clip card experience :( I know, it sucks

Comment: I experienced the same issue as @budidino: it didn't work with the normal camera. Had to use the QR Scanner from Control Center. Thank you budidino for finding that. I got really frustrated why it didn't work. [Using iOS 14.0, non-beta and XCode 12 non-beta]

Comment: didn't work with the normal camera, always showing a "Website-QR-Code" Banner

Comment: the URL PREFIX should only contain the associated domain e.g "https://example.com" and not the URL scanned with QR or NVC like "https://example.com/order?smoothie=carrot-chops" otherwise you will see an App Clip Card with an Error-Message instead of your registered Local Experience Data.